# Cannot make a label wider

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this reproducible code, and I cannot understand why when I set the width value to 100 in the self.display_tcm_18 variable, it still does not increase its width. This self.display_tcm_18 lies within the self.xf Frame, which I set to a width value of 300 (wide enough to host a Label widget of 100). I don't know what I am missing in the Logic of building this GUI with tkinter. Does anyone could give me some hint?

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

class Window(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master = None):

        self.master = master 
        path = "logo.gif"
        self.image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=path)
        self.f = Frame(master, width=300, height =70)
        self.sf = Frame(master, width=300, height=70)
        self.xf = Frame(self.f,width = 300, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth = 2)

        self.file_name_18 = ''

        self.var = IntVar()

        def browse_button():
            filename = askopenfilename(filetypes = (("GEOTIFF Files", "*.tif"),))
            self.file_name = filename 
            self.display.config(text = filename)
            print(self.file_name)


        self.Logo = Label(self.master, image = self.image).pack(side=TOP, padx=5)

        self.open_tcm_button = Button(self.xf, text = "Open..", command = browse_button).pack(side=LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 10)
        self.display_tcm_18 = Label(self.xf, width = 100, bg = "white", textvariable = self.file_name_18, relief = SUNKEN, anchor = W)
        self.display_tcm_18.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.tcm18_label = Label(self.f, text = "Tree Cover Mask 2018 ").place(relx=0.06, rely=0.125,anchor=W)
        self.xf.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.125, anchor=NW)
        self.f.pack(side=TOP)

root = Tk() 
root.geometry("600x400")
app = Window(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `width` for a `Label` is the number of character if the `Label` does not contain an image.